# Como implementar reCAPTCHA do google usando asp classico

Tags: asp, google, recaptcha

Olá,

Não consigo fazer a implantação do `recaptcha` usando o `ASP` clássico.

As dicas do site do google estão me confundindo e eu não consigo implementar.
Alguém poderia me passar um "be a bá" com os passos? As chaves eu já tenho!

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! Para que a comunidade possa te ajudar, é importante que se explique detalhadamente o seu problema. Seria muito interessante adicionar o que você fez até agora. 

Sugiro que leio os artigos: [Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e [como realizar uma pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Se você já tem a chave, você deve substituir no código abaixo:

**File name: GoogleCaptcha.asp**

```
<%@LANGUAGE=VBSCRIPT%>
<%
    Option Explicit
%>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    </head>

    <body>

<%
    If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" Then
        Dim recaptcha_secret, sendstring, objXML
        ' Secret key
        recaptcha_secret = "6LfUUwgTAAAAAMQy5tz9u1BMSnCQV1CVh5tuBcEF"

        sendstring = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" & recaptcha_secret & "&response=" & Request.form("g-recaptcha-response")

        Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        objXML.Open "GET", sendstring, False

        objXML.Send

        Response.write "<h3>Response: " & objXML.responseText & "</h3>"

        Set objXML = Nothing
    End If
%>

        <form method="post" action="GoogleCaptcha.asp">
            <!-- ///////////// SUA CHAVE ABAIXO ///////////// -->
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="---CHAVE--"></div>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Try">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Em funcionamento: http://1click.lv/googlecaptcha.asp

Fonte: [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30735079/2386142) e [Esse artigo](http://kbase.icbconsulting.com/asp/using-google-recaptcha-version-2-0-using-classic-asp)

Comment: Olá pessoal, Eu fui atrás e consegui fazer. Para que precisa vou deixar a explicação:

Answer (score 0):

Eu fui atrás e consegui fazer. Sò faltava fazer uma validadação para redirecionar de acordo com a resposta do google:

Fiz o seguinte::

Logo após o script:  objXML.Send. Digite o texto abaixo:

'Rotina criada por geovan mello, para redirecionar de acordo com sua vontade
        Dim ProcuraString, ProcuraChar, MinhaPos
        ProcuraString =objXML.responseText ' String onde procurar
        ProcuraChar = "false" ' Procurar por "false"
        MinhaPos = Instr(4, ProcuraString, ProcuraChar, 1)

```
     if MinhaPos = "16" then
     response.Redirect("arquivo_de_erro.asp")
     end if
    Set objXML = Nothing
```